# How to connect to MySQL from .Net Core

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core

I am porting and ASP.Net framework / SQL Server application to ASP.Net Core / MySQL.

I am having problems finding documentation which shows how I can interface my existing code which I have ported to .Net Core to a MySQL database.

Has anyone done this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please re-open this question as it is not off topic as described in the help center. The question is asking how to interface the netcore run time with a mysql database, how is this not programming related?

Answer (score 1):

You can't find any documentation because it doesn't exist. Check here:
[EF Doc](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/mysql/index.html)

Comment: thank you for posting and including a link. I think I may have found a way through with npgsql

Comment: This may have been the correct answer at the time, however it now appears to be out of date.

Comment: For anyone who lands on this question (like me) see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/mysql/ and here: https://damienbod.com/2016/08/26/asp-net-core-1-0-with-mysql-and-entity-framework-core/

Comment: https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/tutorials/net-core-mvc/